# Why do some HalconDotNet procedures produce HTuple instead of preferred type?

Tags: c#, 3d, halcon

One example is: `HOperatorSet.RigidTransObjectModel3d()`

It expects `HTuple` but also accept `objectModel3D` as model input. The model output is `HTuple`, even tho it should (imo) be objectModel3D, as a result I cannot use the objectModel3D's `WriteObjectModel3d()` functionality.

Is there a way around this this so I end up with an `objectModel3D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use HOperatorSet, it can be done directly from HObjectModel3D:

```
        HObjectModel3D hObjectModel3D = new HObjectModel3D(HTuple.TupleRand(10), HTuple.TupleRand(10), HTuple.TupleRand(10));

        HPose hPose = new HPose(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, "Rp+T", "gba", "point");
        HObjectModel3D objectModel3DRig = hObjectModel3D.RigidTransObjectModel3d(hPose);
        objectModel3DRig.WriteObjectModel3d("om3", @"C:\temp\temp2.om3", new HTuple(), new HTuple());
```

Comment: How about when using `SelectPointsObjectModel3d` (only available from HOperSet) It returns HTuple, How can I `WriteObjectModel3d` this?

Comment: SelectPointsObjectModel3d is available from both HOperatorSet and object oriented C# (you can see that in documentation - there are 5 different tabs). But if you still want you can use HOperatorSet.WriteObjectModel3d() and use the tuple as a first variable.

Comment: I got it from the docu and tried it but It didnt work, my mistake was that even from reading in the om3 I got a HTuple instead of ObjMod3D, didnt expect that. But thank you for clearing up the `WriteObjectModel3d` that really helped.